# A variable whose domain is one value.

Tags: logic

Is there a meaningful difference between a constant a variable whose set of values is a singleton set? Does it make a difference in terms of interpretation to view a variable as having a domain of a single element, does the nature of interpretation eventually result in a constant in our language? Can this exist in my language, or will it always be a constant?

Comment: In mathematical logic there is a difference because variable symbols and constant symbols are part of the syntax of a language where a domain for the variables or an interpretation of the constant symbols is semantic.

Comment: A variable has no interpretation,  its interpretation changes according to the domain and the specific assignment.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so if it's domain is {$a$}  does $x$ become a 'constant' in my language?

Comment: You can think of it as a constant in certain situations that helps, but formally it's still a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the relevant syntactic characterisations, taken generally, there is a significant difference between an individual constant $\alpha$ and a variable $x$ that is bound to be interpreted as $\alpha$. An informal explication by an imaginary situation will, I presume, clarify the underlying idea.

Suppose there is a room entirely empty except for "a thing" X. We might have sufficient knowledge about X and a name for it. Then, we could speak about X by uttering its name. Or, we might not have a name for it, but our language might be expressive enough to describe X definitely so that we could pick it out unambiguously and speak about it in its particularity. Alternatively, we might have a facility to pick it out ostensively, which would be out of question if we intended to speak about an abstract entity.

But suppose we had neither a name for it nor a language with sufficient resources to describe it nor a facility of ostension. We would still speak about X by referring to it as "the thing in the room" or by general features we had observed on it, for example, saying of it "blue cube-like thing", though such things are abundant and not specific to X, because we would have managed to refer to it by coincidence -that there is nothing else in the room. Thus, though we would speak about X, we could not make specific statements about it.

Hence, the case of a constant $\alpha$ and a variable $x$ invariantly interpreted as $\alpha$ cannot be considered separately from the formal language in which they are expressed.