# Can I have a variable with one value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, terminology

From what I've seen in my introduction to logic, there is a difference between a 'constant', a symbol that is introduced as part of the language and a variable whose domain is simply a single value.

In this context we can have a variable $x∈A$ and $A=$ {$1$}, and make statements like:

$P(x)=(x=1)$

$∀xP(x)$

Although we only have a domain for $x$ of one element $x$ is distinct from a constant as we could not do any of the quantification statements on it if it was simply a constant symbol of my language.

Can we have the same in normal mathematical contexts or would such a 'variable' simply be known as a constant, with a variable needing more than a single value to be a 'variable' in the sense of changing?

Comment: A variable is a variable and not a constant: they are different syntactical objects. Having said that, if we interpret the formula $\forall x P(x)$ is a single-element domain $A = \{ 1 \}$, what we have is that $A \vDash \forall x P(x)$ iff $A,s \vDash P(x)$ for every variable assignment $s$. But, due to the fact that in $A$ there is only the element $1$, we have that $s(x)=1$.

Comment: Variables are part of the language while their values are element of the domain of the chosen interpretation. We have a formula and the corresponding interpretation but, due to the fact that there are possibly more than one interpretation, the "reference" to the interpretation is not part of the language itself.

Comment: I haven't found it necessary to make formal distinctions between constants and variables.

Comment: @Dan4Christensen I guess we can say the only difference is in one a given statment is entirely true, and in the other '$x$' as to be formally 'assigned' it's value first, it makes no difference in practice.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $s(x)$ is a function applied to the symbol $'x'$ or the value $x$? I assume its the variable assignment function?

Comment: This issue has been raised before, see [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4537729/754923)